# How to use a language identifier at the start of url

Tags: php, url, multilingual

I'm using: http://localhost/en/index.php to indetify the current sites language.

But, I'm searching a way to do like this : http://en.localhost/index.php

Maybe some webserver configurations or frameworks would help.

After all my research I wasn't able to find a solution.
Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: It's depend on you how to use create sub domain or add extra parameter in url

Comment: This is too broad to answer, but you have to set DNS Wildcard on your domain first, and then use URL Rewriting to achieve that.

Comment: Sorry, I got no idea from where to start with. That's why it's broad, If I had some tips I wasn't asking here and researching instead. I never asked to write a tutorial for me, just some tip that could support my research. Thank you.

Comment: @Heru-Luin y it should be, thank you ! I got everything I needed.

Comment: @Vladimir We are not here to help you with your research or "get you started".

Comment: @Epodax So why are you here ?

Comment: @Vladimir To help people who do their research and have actual coding problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of options you can do if you use a `wildcard` domain configuration. Say you have this following entry in the DNS:

```
*.example.com    127.0.0.1
example.com      127.0.0.1
```

This will redirect all the domains and sub-domains under `example.com` to one single place. Such thing can be configured in Apache too.

```
ServerName   example.com
ServerAlias  *.example.com
```

And they all go to the same location. In PHP, you can use:

```
$lang = str_replace(".example.com", "", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
```

And based on the variable in the `$lang` you can make it. If you wanna do it for `localhost`, you need to set your Apache directive this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    <Directory "C:/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, and principally for not hashing about my ignorance. If I could I'd give you way more points for this.

Comment: @Vladimir All the best. Glad that I could help. Once I was also like this.